# Why am I getting a Ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49) when adding a schema to ldap?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openldap

My first time trying to marry LDAP as a backend to Samba. I'm following the instructions at: [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-ldap.html) and I'm stumbling when I get to the part 5 with the following error: "ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)" Googling has pointed me towards the slapd.conf file but I don't have one in the /etc/ldap directory or anywhere on disk despite having installed ldap twice and running a dpkg-reconfigure twice.
Has the configuration file for slapd been changed recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP 49 is basically failed to connect for credential reasons.  Could be a bad DN.  Could be a bad password.  Could be a locked account, and so on.

Comment: This isn't an issue with what you are trying to do per se, but an issue of having the correct user & password.  Also note that OpenLDAP supports the config being part of the database now, so having a slapd.conf is optional http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#Configuration Layout